# Toeplitz matrix initialization

Tags: java, toeplitz

I am trying to initialize a Toeplitz matrix in java. I want it to have this form
`6 -4 1 0 0 ... 0
-4 6 -4 1 0 ... 0
 1 -4 6 -4 1 ...0
 ................
 0 ... 1 -4 6 -4 1
 0 ... ...1 -4 6-4
 0 .. ... 0 1 -4 6`

I realized that the problem is in the `if(j>i)` in the bounds of `data[i-j-1]` . I tried to change it but i get the `IndexOutOfBounds` error. Here is the code i've written so far

```
    int a1[][] = new int[size][size];


    int data[] = new int[size];

    data[0] = 6;
    data[1] = -4;
    data[2] = 1;

    for(int i=3; i<size; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }

    /* Creating the A1 matrix */
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(j>i){
                a1[i][j] = data[j-i-1];

            }else if(j==i){
                a1[i][j] = data[0];

            }else{
                a1[i][j] = data[i-j-1];
            }


        }
    }
```

And the output is

```
    The Matrix is : 
6   6   -4  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   
6   6   6   -4  1   0   0   0   0   0   
-4  6   6   6   -4  1   0   0   0   0   
1   -4  6   6   6   -4  1   0   0   0   
0   1   -4  6   6   6   -4  1   0   0   
0   0   1   -4  6   6   6   -4  1   0   
0   0   0   1   -4  6   6   6   -4  1   
0   0   0   0   1   -4  6   6   6   -4  
0   0   0   0   0   1   -4  6   6   6   
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   -4  6   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if `i = j+1` or `j = i+1`, `a1` is assigned `a1[i][j] = data[0]`. This is an off-by-one mistake, you should remove the 1:

```
for(int j=0; j<size; j++) {
    if(j>i){
        a1[i][j] = data[j-i];
    }else if(j==i){
        a1[i][j] = data[0];
    }else{
        a1[i][j] = data[i-j];
    }
}
```